# URI matching for @QueryParam in Java Jersey Jax-RS

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs

How do I do the equivalent of this `@Path` param using query parameters?

> @Path("/history/{startDate: [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-1][0-9]-[0-3][0-9]}/{endDate: [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-1][0-9]-[0-3][0-9]}")

Which would match this URI:

`/history/1914-01-20/2014-01-20/`

But now I need to match this:

`/history/123456?end=2024-01-20&start=2014-11-12`

This code works, but there is no validation against the `start` param and `end` param:

> @Path("/history")
>
> public Response getHistory( 
>                                     @QueryParam("start") String start,

```
                              @QueryParam("end") String end){
```

> /*** foo ***/
>
> }

Comment: There's no URI "matching" for query parameters. They're not part of the path. If a path match is found, you should just validate the date yourself or some other form of validation, _post_ path matching. That's the purpose of query params, so they can be used for processing. Paths are used for matching to locate a resource, that's not the job of query params

Comment: I guess I could just do a regex check?

Answer (score 0):

Wich version of JAX-RS (or Jersey) are you using?

From version 2 you can use Bean Validation (https://weblogs.java.net/blog/bhaktimehta/archive/2013/10/30/jax-rs-and-bean-validation )

Or a bit more complex in the case of your example, Entities Providers like

[Jax-RS MessageBodyReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24153827/jax-rs-messagebodyreader)

https://blogs.oracle.com/arungupta/entry/jax_rs_custom_entity_providers

But is for version JAX-RS 2.

Answer (score 0):

Since I was told there is no "matching" for query parameters, I found two other ways to handle this:

**Method #1: Using Regular Expressions**

```
//in my includes
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

//In my @GET endpoint
Pattern startPattern = Pattern.compile("[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-1][0-9]-[0-3][0-9]");
        Matcher startMatcher = startPattern.matcher(assigned);

        if (startMatcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("Matched!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Did not match!");
        }
```

**Method #2: Require a certain data type in your implementation**

I can't really codify this as it's specific to your implementation, but in my implementation, I required a TIMESTAMPTZ for my database row. Jax-RS then throws an error when the `QueryParam` doesn't match during an SQL query.